# Python return the row length for first record

Tags: python

I have code that will go through a text file and determine different types of rows based on category and in one case type field in that specific row. Next, for each category (i.e. paying customers), I want to return the row length for just the first row.

Currently the code is reading through all the rows that meets this "paying customer" criteria. The end goal is essentially to determine the row length for each category (paying customer and terminated customers).

Within a single file the row length for each category is always the same – meaning every "paying customer" row is the same length and everything "terminated customer" row is the same length but the "paying customer" and "terminated customer" rows do not have the same length.

Instead of getting the row length for every "customer paying" and every "terminated customer" row, I'd like to just read the first row that meets the "customer paying" criteria and fetch the row length for that, similarly for "terminated customer". It's not necessary to read all of the "customer paying" rows in the file – this could be upwards to 600000 rows.

How would I refactor this code?

```
file = "testfile.txt"
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        new_line = line.rstrip()
        category = line[43]
        type = line[44]
        if category == "1":
            if type == "5":
                category = "paying_customers"
                type15_len = len(new_line)
            else:
                category = "terminated_customers"
                type1_len = len(new_line)
        else:
            print("Done")
```

Update:
A follow-up question related to this... since I have to scan the file anyways for multiple categories, do I actually gain any benefit by breaking out?

In some files, the first instance of an a category (i.e. terminated_customers may occur at row 400,000). Also, in this example, I had to mock up something that is similar to my code. But, in actuality, I have a few more elif sections as there are more categories.

I assume with each if/elif statement, a new scan of the file is started? If that's the case, would it benefit me at all to have a break?

I apologize for so many questions!

Comment: As soon as both lengths are more than zero - break out of your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do like this: break once both vars are true

```
file = "testfile.txt"


read_row_paying_c, read_row_terminated_c = False, False
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        if read_row_paying_c and read_row_terminated_c:
            break
        new_line = line.rstrip()
        category = line[43]
        type_ = line[44]
        if category == "1":
            if type_ == "5":
                category = "paying_customers"
                type15_len = len(new_line)
                read_row_paying_c =True
            else:
                category = "terminated_customers"
                type1_len = len(new_line)
                read_row_terminated_c = True
        else:
            print("Done")
```

also I would suggest you to rename `type` variable to `type_` as there is a built-in function with the same name

Comment: I know this will be a dumb question. I am new to coding/programming, so I don't totally follow the logic above. What is this concept called? I would like to read up on it to better understand. >.<

Comment: @TechNewbie you set a condition to terminate the for loop using the `break` instruction. the break condition is that both boolean variables  `read_row_terminated_c` and `read_row_paying_c` are evaluated to True. So basically everytime you move to the next row in your file you evaluate this condition if it is true then you "break" from the for loop and your program ends, if the condition is False you continue reading your file as normal. Hope this is clear

Comment: you can accept the answer if it is correct for your need